# Latexmk: Stop processing on pdflatex error

Tags: errors, latexmk

If my tex-files contain an error (such as an undefined control sequence), latexmk will present a prompt and ask for manual input before continuing. Now, of course it is possible to force further processing, e.g. as described here [Don't make me manually abort a LaTeX compile when there's an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738755/dont-make-me-manually-abort-a-latex-compile-when-theres-an-error) or here [Make latexmk ignore errors and finish compiling](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120019/make-latexmk-ignore-errors-and-finish-compiling).

However, in case of an error I would like Latexmk to stop processing completely and to return to the command line. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Comment: I have this in my `.latexmkrc`: `$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1  -halt-on-error %O %S";` In my case I tend to use `-pvc` all the time, so here it just stops the compilation if there is an error and go back to waiting for change. You can also use the `-interaction=...` option. If I'm not mistaken you can also pass these on to pdflatex via `latexmk` CLI options.

Comment: I'll convert it into an answer

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I have this in my `.latexmkrc`:

```
$pdflatex = "pdflatex -synctex=1 -halt-on-error %O %S";
```

In my case I tend to use `-pvc` all the time, so here it just stops the compilation if there is an error and go back to waiting for change. You can also use the `-interaction=...` option.

If I'm not mistaken you can also pass these on to `pdflatex` via `latexmk` CLI options

Reading `latexmk --help` you can actually use `latexmk -halt-on-error` directly

Comment: What do all the flags mean? Especially the "synctex", and the "%O" and "%S"?

Comment: @muuh synctex is a feature used for reverse search communication, aka the ability to go from the PDF (in a suitable pdf viewer) to the corresponding source line in an editor. For the others see http://personal.psu.edu/jcc8//software/latexmk-jcc/latexmk-467.txt under "FORMAT OF COMMAND SPECIFICATIONS"